# MySQL database foreign key referencing multiple records, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a weak entity called Pizza which is identified by its Pizza.name attribute and an identifying relation called Dough.
Pizzas also have toppings but for example an 8" Ham Pizza and a 12" Ham Pizza have the same toppings. These toppings also have a cost associated with them.

---

With this information I've created the table Pizza(name, Dough.size), the table ToppingOf(Pizza.name, Ingredient.name) and the table Ingredient(name, cost) here Pizza.name being a foreign key referencing the name attribute of Pizza

---

Now an example to illustrate the problem, say I have:

- Pizza("Ham Pizza", 8)
- Pizza("Ham Pizza", 12)
- ToppingOf("Ham Pizza",    "ham")
- Ingredient("ham", 2)

In case of an ON DELETE RESTRICT constraint I can't delete pizzas.
With an ON DELETE CASCADE constraint deleting the 8" Ham Pizza would delete ToppingOf resulting in the 12" Ham Pizza not having any. Making the Pizza reference the ToppingOf table with RESTRICT wouldn't allow me to delete a record from the ToppingOf table and with CASCADE it would delete the Pizza as well.

---

I would like to be able to delete a pizza without it deleting the topping.

This was a homework assignment and I ended up storing the toppings individually for every size of ham pizza, but I would like to know if there is a better way to handle things in this situation.

Comment: `pizza` should reference `topping` not the other way around.

Comment: in that case deleting a topping would also delete the pizza which is also undesirable

Comment: Then don't set `ON DELETE CASCADE`. If you set deletes cascading, they'll be cascaded... If you don't want that, don't set them cascading. You may want `ON DELETE SET NULL`, if a pizza without topping makes sense in your model.

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship (every pizza may have multiple toppings and a topping may be used on multiple pizzas), not a one-to-many. You need an extra table between the two you have at the moment. See answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: I know and I seem to have oversimplified the problem while giving the example, check the edit.

Comment: Not really sure what's the updated question beyond the many-to-many relationship. Your cascaded delete would delete the records from the junction table only, leaving your toppings intact.